# Change bar color in chart.js depending on value

Tags: javascript, colors, charts, bar-chart

I want to create a bar chart using chart.js (www.chartjs.org). The bar fill color should change depending on the value.

E.g., if the value is less than 10, color is green, 11-15 means yellow, and 16-20 is red.

Is it possible to do that with chart.js, and how?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't find a way of doing this using chart.js, and switched to google visualization.

There it can be done like this:

```
 // first index in chartData array describes the fields in the following indexes,
 // The first two are the X and Y values, role: style tells the chart to use the third
 // field as the style of that particular bar. role: annotation tells the chart to 
 // add the contents of the fourth field as a label to each bar.
 var chartHeader = [['Time', 'Measurement', { role: 'style' }, { role: 'annotation' }]];

 function ConvertJsonToChartData(json) {
        var chartData = chartHeader;

        for (var key in json) {
            var x = json[key].X;
            var elapsedTime = json[key].ElapsedTime;

            // set style based on value of elapsedTime
            var style = 'black';
            if (elapsedTime > GlobalSettings['criticalThreshold']) {
                style = GlobalSettings['criticalColor'];
            } else if(elapsedTime > GlobalSettings['warningThreshold']) {
                style = GlobalSettings['warningColor'];
            }

            // add a new datapoint to the chart
            chartData.push([x, elapsedTime, style, elapsedTime]);
        }
        return chartData;
    }

    function MakeHourGraph(json) {
        var chartData = ConvertJsonToChartData(json);

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

        var options = {
            title: 'Response Times',
            hAxis: { title: 'Hour', titleTextStyle: { color: 'blue' } },
            vAxis: { title: 'msecs', titleTextStyle: { color: 'blue' } },
            legend: { position: "none" }
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('hour_chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Chartjs actually allows for `background-color` to be an array, so you can provide an array of colors according to what you need. This means that you can create the colors where you create the data set. In my own case I didn't something like:

```
    backgroundColor: [
        <?=$color?>
        ],
    data: [
        <?=$tableData;?>
    ],
```

where `$color` was something like `'rgba(0,255,0,1)','rgba(255,0,0,1)',` and $tableData was something like `1,-1`.

I was pushing the data from the server using php, but if you want to do something just in JavaScript the sample below may help you.

[This is the right way to set the colors of each bar on a Chartjs chart.](https://forums.asp.net/t/2145737.aspx?ChartJS%20Bar%20Graph%20Background%20Color%20based%20on%20dataset%20value)

I got the sample below from NanYu at the link above.

```
var chartColors = {
  color1: 'rgba(77, 166, 255, 0.5)',
  color2: 'rgba(218, 165, 32, 0.5)',
  color3: 'rgba(175, 0, 42, 0.5)'
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3', 'value 4'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      backgroundColor: [
        chartColors.color1,
        chartColors.color1,
        chartColors.color1,
        chartColors.color1
      ],
      data: [29, 57, 65, 42]
    }],
  }
});

var colorChangeValue = 50; //set this to whatever is the deciding color change value
var dataset = myChart.data.datasets[0];
for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
  if (dataset.data[i] < 30) {
    dataset.backgroundColor[i] = chartColors.color1;
  }
  else if ((dataset.data[i] > 31) && (dataset.data[i] <= 60)){
    dataset.backgroundColor[i] = chartColors.color2;
  }
  else{
   dataset.backgroundColor[i] = chartColors.color3;
  }
}
myChart.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Very old post but for the people that come here from Google search there **is** a way to do this with ChartJS.

You can transform your data to 2 datasets:
- 1st with the positive values, replacing all the negative values with 0
- 2nd with the negative values, replacing all the positive values with 0

```
originalSet = [1,-1, 3,-3, 5]
positiveSet = [1, 0, 3, 0, 5]
negativeSet = [0,-1, 0,-3, 0]
```

Then simply add the color of your choice for each set:

```
datasets: [
  { data: positiveSet, backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.5)' },
  { data: negativeSet, backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)' }
]
```

This method can be applied not only for positive/ negative separation, but in general when you want to style based on values.

Answer (score -1):

I've never used chart.js, but this would be my suggestion...

```
Chart.defaults.global = { //this has all the information for the chart, I just removed everything else
    // String - Colour of the scale line
    scaleLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.1)"
}
```

I would so something like....

```
if (number < 10) { Chart.defaults.global.scaleLineColor = "rgba(whatever)" }
```

Then just fill it in with all of your code and such. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: That will change the color for all bars in the graph, I only want to change color on those bars which represent values larger than a threshold. The lower ones should keep their color.

Comment: Ah, I guess I missed that part of it. But glad you got it figured out! Sorry I couldn't be of more help.